# How to control unwanted Pop-up that appear when making call within app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, popup

I am developing an app about making call and returning to app when calling ended. Here is my code;

```
**callWebview = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
        NSURL *telUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:4444484"];
        [callWebview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:telUrl]];**
```

This is ok but when url request is being sent, A pop up appears on the screen.

[image: Call message]

This is the screenshot when I press the button and run the code at upside;

[image]

So , Here is my question;

1. Can I block this pop up to appear on the screen ?
2. If I can't how can I change the message body and buttons of this popup ?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not use the `UIWebView` the message will not appear, but then you will not be able to come beck to the app.

To make a call with out the alert:

```
NSURL *telUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:4444484"];
// Check if the iOS device support dialing a number
if ( [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:telUrl]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:telUrl];
}
```

But there is no solution that will do exactly what you desire, so either it is the dialog or no dialog but not retuning to you app.

Comment: Ok I see, There is a framework named coretelephony.I can detect if calling finished with the codes. : (#import <CoreTelephony/CTCall.h> )  So can I return the app with this framework ?

Comment: No, you can get your app to come to the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead:

```
NSURL *telUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:4444484"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:telUrl];
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I want. I have to turn back to the app. This code doesn't work for my purpose.